# Algorithm to determine the maximum number of points placeable in a surface

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I´m trying to find the maximum number of point that I can place in a given surface considering that the points have to present a certain distance between themselves.

I had thought to discretize the surface with a small resolution and try all combinations. Unfortunately, this method is very slow.Another solution could be the search of valid points and from each valid position search new valid points using a recursive function. Altough this method is faster, its computation time grows exponentially with the surface.

So, I wonder if it exists other algorithm that permits a faster solution.

My code in C is as follows:

```
int locatePoints(int p_valids, int achieved, int points[][2]){

int row_ini;
int row_end;

int points_max[N][2];
int points_act[N][2];
int valids_act;
int quantity_max;

int valid;
int point_to5;
int SquaredDistance;

int i,j,k,l;


if (p_valids==0){
    row_ini = 0;
}
else{
    row_ini = points[p_valids-1][0];
}
row_end = row_ini+6;
if (row_end>ROW_LIMIT){
    row_end = ROW_LIMIT;
}

for(i=0;i<p_valids;i++){
    points_act[i][0] = points[i][0];
    points_act[i][1] = points[i][1];
    points_max[i][0]=points[i][0];
    points_max[i][1]=points[i][1];
}

quantity_max = p_valids;


for(i=row_ini;i<row_end;i++){
    for(j=0;j<COL_LIMIT;j++){
        valid = 1;
        point_to5 = 0;
        for (k=0;k<p_valids && valid;k++){
            SquaredDistance = (points[k][0]-i)*(points[k][0]-i)+(points[k][1]-j)*(points[k][1]-j);
            if (SquaredDistance<25){
                if (SquaredDistance<16){
                    valid = 0;
                }
                else{
                    point_to5++;
                    if (point_to5>1){
                        valid = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (valid){
            points_act[p_valids][0] = i;
            points_act[p_valids][1] = j;

            valids_act = locatePoints(p_valids+1, quantity_max, points_act);
            if (valids_act>quantity_max){
                quantity_max = valids_act;
                for(k=0;k<quantity_max;k++){
                    points_max[k][0]=points_act[k][0];
                    points_max[k][1]=points_act[k][1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for(k=0;k<quantity_max;k++){
    points[k][0]= points_max[k][0];
    points[k][1]= points_max[k][1];
}
return quantity_max;
```

}

Comment: What shape is the surface?

Comment: Just now I am using a square surface, but it is really defined by five or six first order functions in a shape close to a trapezoid. I had thought to add to the sqare surface a limitation of valid positions to solve it.

Comment: So what kind of distance-constraints are there? It might be more wise to describe these instead of forcing people to reconstruct it from your code. Assuming, that the points should keep a minimum-distance from each other, this is a *circle packing problem* which might be np-hard.

Comment: I only put my code to provide an idea about what I have been doing, but the algorithm is no efficient and there is no case in reconstructing it. I was in fact asking for a new algorithm as the circle packing problem, although I don´t know if it will work. The constraints are that the distance between all points has to be higher than 5 except two points for each other that can be at a distance of 4

Comment: FWIW discretizing the space doesn't actually work in a theoretical sense, there are instances where you will necessarily miss a required point because the coordinates are irrational. But practically it *has* to be discrete, irrational numbers can't be computed or stored. Anyway you could try QCQP, despite the NP-hardness this is probably more effective than brute force.